# Can't understand the output of the following Java expression. It should be just an exercise of operator precedence and associativity

Tags: java, operators

Here is the expression:

```
class ExpresieUrata
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int x = 101;
        int y = ( x+= (x *= 3) % ((x++ >> 2 ) - 1) ) ^ 40;
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

I I get the output 68 but can't figure out why. I came to the conclusion that before the XOR operation I will get 108, made out of 101 + 7, but can't figure out why - especially the 7.

Can someone tell me the exact order of operation and value of x in storage/used at all steps?

Comment: Ok, I am dumb, after a 5 minute break to refresh my eyes I figured it out sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int x = 101;
        int y = ( x+= (x *= 3) % ((x++ >> 2 ) - 1) );
        //int y = ( x+= (x *= 3) % ((x++ >> 2 ) - 1) ) ^ 40;
        int z = y ^ 40;
        System.out.printf("X: %d Y: %d Z: %d\n", x, y, z);
        System.out.printf("303 >> 2 == %d\n", 303 >> 2);
        System.out.printf("303 %% 74 == %d\n", (303 % 74));
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
X: 108 Y: 108 Z: 68
303 >> 2 == 75
303 % 74 == 7
```

x *= 3 gets you the 303. 303 >> 2 is 75. Now subtract 1 is 74. 303 % 74 is 7. The x+= bit uses the original value of X before all the side effects, so 101 + 7 == 108.

And OMG, this is freakishly evil, and I would have unkind words if I ever saw code like this.

Comment: Managed to hack it down in a similar way. It is an exercise after the first java class from my Java fundamentals course that I took at a cisco academy in around 2005. The side efects are criminal and the x++ gets discarded because x = 101 + 7 will override the 303 to 304 change. I am so scared of side effects that I don't use while(a[i++] != b[j++]), and I am a C/C++ programmer.

Comment: Pre- and post-increment/decrement operators are pretty safe when used sanely. But  I don't even know the sort of mindset of someone who would write this exercise. A better exercise is, "tell me several reasons you shouldn't write code like this".

Comment: It;s one of the first things you learn, the operators and precedence.